# Conditionally add class to body based on window.location.hostname?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a site for a company that operates in both New Zealand and Australia, and who has company.co.nz and company.com.au domains pointed at the same website.

The below code is meant to add the class "australia" to the body when the site is accessed via company.com.au so I can make some CSS styling tweaks to colours and things:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $pathname = window.location.hostname;
    console.log( $pathname );
    if ( $pathname = 'company.com.au' ) {
        $('body').addClass( 'australia' );
    }
});
```

The console logs the correct hostname in both instances, but it always adds the "australia" class to the body.

I assume it is just matching the "company" part, rather than the full address. Any ideas how I may better implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are missing the comparison bit by just putting one `=` in the if statement. Change it to `==`:

```
if ( $pathname == 'company.com.au' ) {
    $('body').addClass( 'australia' );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is an assignment, not a condition. Assignments will always evaluate to their value (in this case `'company.com.au'`), and then this value is evaluated to a boolean (`console.log('company.com.au' ? true : false)` returns `true`):

```
if ( $pathname = 'company.com.au' ) {
```

Change it to a condition instead:

```
if ( $pathname == 'company.com.au' ) {
```

And as a small reminder, Javascript doesn't require `$` before variable names.

Answer (score 0):

because you are redeclaring $pathname to 'company.com.au'.

this should be like :

```
if ( $pathname == 'company.com.au' ) {
        $('body').addClass( 'australia' );
}
```

Be careful with declarations and equality.

Hope this helps :)